# Уместно ли в данном случае тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Яблоки и апельсины — без червей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, постановка тире в таком предложении возможна. Нет, правда, контекста. Пофантазируем.

1. Возможный диалог.
   — Все фрукты в прошлом году были червивые.
   **— Яблоки и апельсины — без червей.** [пропущено сказуемое "были"]

Еще возможное предложение.
Почти все фрукты в прошлом году были червивые, а яблоки и апельсины — без червей.

§ 6.5. Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое) восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска делается пауза:
*Мир освещается солнцем, а человек — знанием* (пословица).

2. Можно составить такое (абстрактное) предложение.
   Мы купили разные фрукты: груши и сливы — с червяками, **яблоки и апельсины — без червей.**

§ 6.6. Тире ставится в однотипно построенных частях сложного предложения при пропуске какого-либо члена и даже без пропуска: *Они смотрели друг на друга: Райский — с холодным любопытством, она — с дерзким торжеством* (Гончаров).

[Тире в неполном предложении](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827474.html)

3. — Что купили?
   — [Мы купили] Яблоки и апельсины без червей.
   В этом предложении тире, конечно же, не требуется.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое  !

Answer (score 3):

Если это не часть предложения, где "*без червей*" может являться несогласованным определением для "*яблок и апельсинов*", а цельная фраза, то тире очень даже уместно.

[**§ 7. Интонационное тире**](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827474.html)

> Тире ставится для указания места распадения простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы подчеркнуть или уточнить смысловые отношения между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен.
>
> Такое тире называется интонационным, оно может отделять **любую** часть предложения: *...Неостановимо, невосстановимо хлещет жизнь. Подставляйте миски и тарелки! Всякая тарелка будет — мелкой, миска — плоской* (Цв.); *Беру бинокль — наблюдать*; *К станции приближались пешеходы — с узлами, мешками, чемоданами* — однородные члены предложения относятся к сказуемому и имеют значение дополнения, а при отсутствии тире могли бы быть восприняты как несогласованные определения к подлежащему.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое !

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Разве у новичков появилось право голосовать за ответы?! раньше было только право принять ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: @behemothus  Я еще сам новичок — не знаю всех правил.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец тем более должны помнить. )))

Comment: @behemothus Поначалу было столько всего (сайт очень многофункциональный), что, увы, не отфиксировалось :)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Вот здесь смотрите  https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges  15 баллов нужно.

Comment: @behemothus  Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы так ответил. **Тире возможно, но необходимость его предопределяется контекстом.**

Вам все правильно сказали, но, судя по комментариям, мое уточнение будет не лишним.

Если это просто фраза типа рекламы "(У нас яблоки) и апельсины без червей", тире излишне.
Часто тире в подобных случаях может использоваться как интонационное — для выделения второй части фразы. Тут автор решает, нужно ли оно.
О случаях, когда тире необходимо, вам подробно рассказали в других ответах.

То есть или дайте фрагмент текста побольше, или решайте на свое усмотрение. Ошибки большой в общем-то не будет даже в том случае, когда вы поставите тире там, где оно не требуется по контексту. Но акцент может сместиться.